# Trouble with using Python Visual importing

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to use the visual function in python which I have imported but I am still getting an error saying `"no module named visual"`.

What can i do to fix this?

My code:

```
     from visual import *
```

The error:

```
    line 3, in <module>
    from visual import *
    ImportError: No module named 'visual'
```

Comment: What is visual? Where's it supposed to come from?

Comment: Please make use of the code formatting. You are trying to import the module `visual` which can not be found in your python path. So you need to install it. For this you can use the packet manager `pip`.

Comment: oh okay, that makes sense. i dont think i have it installed. ill give that a try now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you don't have the module 'visual' installed. Have you installed the module?
 If you have installed it that means your IDE isn't finding the module.

Comment: oh okay, that makes sense. i dont think i have it installed. ill give that a try now. thanks

Comment: @SamirHussain Okay! Tell me if it you need help.

Comment: can you explain what the error means and how i can fix it please?

Comment: I have no idea, im sorry! If my soulution worked could you please mark it correct :)?

Answer (score 0):

In python `from something import *` probably means one of:

1. You are trying to import things (functions, variables, classes) from another module in the current path, `something.py`, or `something/__init__.py`.
2. You are trying to import from the module `something` found in the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html).
3. You are trying to import from a 3rd-party module probably installed from the [python package index](https://pypi.python.org) with `pip install something`.

So.... what is `visual` in your case?

Comment: please ask this as a new question. do not use comments for this